# Relation between on scroll and ontouchmove android

Tags: android, touch, onscroll

Does  onscroll event depends from ontouchmove event in Android?When I scroll a page,I use ontouchmove that then make possible onscroll...right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean onTouchEvent?
And yes I think it'll depend on onTouchMove, at least in RecyclerView.

You can check the implementation here in [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#1768)

Comment: Yes I mean ontouch event.What do you mean with "at least in RecyclerView"?

Comment: See the link that I provided, I can provide you a prove in recyclerview but I think the other (ScrollView & ListView) should have similar thing